# Where has my route gone in the Activity app?

Tags: iphone, apple-watch, activity.app

I did a cycle ride at the weekend and recorded the workout on my Apple Watch. When I finished I saved the workout and could see the route in the Activity app on my iPhone.

Now a couple of days later I can view the workout stats such as distance and average speed. However, I can no longer see the route. I can see routes for other workouts.

Has anyone else experienced this and has a fix for it? I'm sure the data is still there

[image: Workout]

Comment: Did you use the same app to record the activity?  I found that one of my exercise apps didn't save the route to Activity.  I could see the detailed data, just like you, but not the route.  Maybe this is similar?

Comment: Yes it was just the built-in workout app. It does sound similar to what you describe although I could view the route for a while before it disappeared.

Comment: In the Activity app is the icon on that specific workout the regular ring or is it a different app?  Just making sure the correct app was used to record the cycle ride.

Comment: Yes, it looks normal to me. I've just added a screenshot to my question.

Comment: Thanks for the screenshot, that helps.  I don't see anything wrong with the workout (29m, holy cow!).  If other, similar workouts have a map then, sorry,  I don't know what to tell you.

Comment: Ok, thanks anyway. Shame I can't show you the route as it involved two ferry crossings and an island. It looked quite good on the map!

Answer (score 1):

I recently had the same issue. I force restarted the watch and the next activity it showed a map again. 
Still testing if it resolved the issue for ever.

Comment: You say that resolved it for the next activity, but what about the one for which the map disappeared?

Answer (score 1):

The only thing that has worked for me is erasing all data from iWatch, unpairing and repairing.

**Un-pair and then re-pair. You will not lose your data. Follow the steps below:**

On your Apple Watch, go to Settings > General > Reset > Erase All Content and Settings.
On your iPhone, open the Watch app and go to My Watch > select your watch > tap the (i) icon > tap Unpair Apple Watch.

Then repair by going to watch in your iphone.  Restore from backup.

Source: https://macreports.com/apple-watch-workout-route-not-showing-in-the-activity-app-fix/